# Catch mouse clicks in python

Tags: python, gtk, xlib

I'm trying to catch mouse click events in my python code (not just clicks in a `Gtk` window I created but anywhere in the screen). After some search, I found a thread talking about `xlib` (great, a dependency I already had).

```
from Xlib import display, X

display = display.Display()
root = display.screen().root
root.change_attribute(event_mask = X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask)

while True:
    event = root.display.next_event()
    print(event)
```

The problem is that this chunk of code is throwing an error and I just can't find good documentation...

```
X protocol error:
<class 'Xlib.error.BadAccess'>: code = 10, resource_id = 146, sequence_number = 9, major_opcode = 2, minor_opcode = 0
```

If you have any idea for this error or another way do this, it'll help really!

Answer (score 0):

`BadAccess` here is because "An attempt is made to select an event type that only one client can select at a time when another client has already selected it."

From [x11 protocol documentation](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.txt), ChangeWindowAttributes request (opcode 2 is this request code, resource id=146 is your root win id):

> Multiple clients can select input on the same window; their
>   event-masks are disjoint. When an event is generated, it will be
>   reported to all interested clients. However, only one client at a time
>   can select for SubstructureRedirect , only one client at a time can
>   select for ResizeRedirect, and only one client at a time can select
>   for ButtonPress. An attempt to violate these restrictions results in
>   an Access error.

Try to select `ButtonReleaseMask` only as a possible solution

Comment: Thanks, that is actually solving the error problem (and your link is in my bookmarks now). But I still can catch mouse press/release events...